# Can't convert JSON result type

Tags: java, json, type-conversion

```
   for(int i=0; i<roomsJSONArr.size(); i++){
            JSONObject curRoom = (JSONObject) roomsJSONArr.get(i);
            int test = (int) curRoom.get("id");
        }
```

Results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at rogue.Rogue.createRooms(Rogue.java:122)
        at rogue.A1Solution.main(A1Solution.java:59)
```

> First: Are all numbers in a JSON file interpreted as Longs?

> Second: Why doesn't this work? It worked for me in other places

Edit: To be more clear, the error was thrown at `int test = (int) curRoom.get("id");`

Comment: Was the exception thrown in the `int test = (int) curRoom.get("id");` line ?

Comment: @Hassan yes, it was

Comment: try ((Number) curRoom.get("id")).intValue() or check does your library has method getInt which you could use

Comment: It's probably an overflow, it happens when the long inside the ID is too large to be held in an integer. You can reproduce it on jshell with something like `Integer i = (Integer) Long.MAX_VALUE`. I wasn't able to reproduce it with `int` though, that's why I asked the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `int test = (int) curRoom.get("id")` try `int test = curRoom.get("id").intValue()`. If this doesn't work then as Hassan said in the comments, it could be an integer overflow. If this is the case, then you could use BigInteger.